# VPN and physical IP routing

Tags: vpn, ip, routing

I was wondering how  I would be able ( if possible ) to do this :

I have a physical machine in a data center with static IP's, I also have a home server who's IP gets reset every 36 hours by the ISP. The ISP does not allow ports lower than 1024.

My homeserver is in a vpn with different other servers. Would it be possible to "route" the static IP to the VPN ip of my homeserver ? In that way I could easily access my home server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup a 'site to site' VPN configuration and allow the VPN router(s) (or consentrator / firewall) do routing for you. But from the what you have written, it looks like you are using a VPN client. Regardless you will need some sort of dynamic hostname service like DynDNS  to create a hostname that points to your home IP address.

The quick drawing below would allow you to establish a VPN tunnel using the dynamic serivce to keep record of your ISPs WAN interface lease.  [image]